# Match more than one element in collection

Tags: scala, scala-2.9

Define:

```
val x = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I want to find if `x` contains either `1` or `3`.
One way is

```
x.contains(1) || x.contains(3)
```

another is

```
x.exists(y => y == 1 || y == 3)
```

and another is:

```
x.exists(List(1,3).contains(_))
```

I would have preferred something similar to

```
x.containsAnyOf(1, 3)
```

Note that `x.containsSlice` does not work in this case.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```
x exists Set(0, 1, 2)
```

Comment: or `x exists (0 to 2).toSet` (preferred for big ranges)

Comment: @4e6: Don't you mean `Set(1, 3)` for my question. I am looking for a match only when it is either `1` or `3`. Also, why the `0` ?

Answer (score 5):

Ofcourse, there's no `containsAnyOf` in Scala's standard library. You can make it look like there is by using the "pimp my library" pattern.

```
class ContainsAnyOf[T](seq: Seq[T]) {
  def containsAnyOf(xs: T*) = seq.exists(xs.contains(_))
}

implicit def seqToContainsAnyOf[T](seq: Seq[T]) = new ContainsAnyOf(seq)
```

Now you can do:

```
scala> val a = List(1,2,3,4)
a: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> a.containsAnyOf(1,3)
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: I laughed for "pimp my library" and then found out you weren't joking!

Comment: @PlastyGrove there have been attempts to change the name of the pattern to "extend my library" or "enrich my library" (see: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pimp-my-library/info), but I'm not sure if any of them has reached the level of popularity of the original name.. :)

Comment: @PaoloFalabella: Well I can see why that would be recommended, but "Pimp my library" just sounds so Badass :). Even more so because it's been used by Martin Odersky as well(http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=179766)